# Why is the stressed form of "of" different in American English than in other English?

Tags: phonology, transatlantic-differences

In UK English, *of* has the stressed pronunciation /ɒv/. In Australian English, it has the corresponding pronunciation /ɔv/. However, in US English, it is /ʌv/ instead of the corresponding /ɑv/. I get that in General American /ʌ/ and /ə/ are really the same phoneme, so that the stressed and unstressed forms have the same phonemes, but what happened to the old stressed form of *of*?

Comment: There are probably 50 different ways to pronounce "of".

Comment: American English speakers can also have ʌ in *wh**a**t, w**a**s, bec**au**se.*

Comment: @herisson Yes, that is true. I wonder if this change only affected words that had a stressed form with ɑ but an unstressed form with ə. It did not affect _and_, for example, which has weak forms with ə but a stressed form with æ, or _for_ with ɚ/ɔɹ.